# Proof of L being a regular languaje

Tags: regular-language

I have the following language

$$L = \{w\in\{a,\;b\}^* : a^nv,\; n\geq 1 \wedge |v|_a \geq n\}$$

Formed by characters "$a$" and "$b$" where the word $v$ has more "$a$" characters than $a^n$.

I have to prove that this is a regular language, but I can't see any way to do that, I think this is not a regular language.

Any ideas on how to prove this?

Answer (score 0):

HINT: Every word in $L$ begins with $a$. And $aw\in L$ if and only if $|w|_a\ge 1$.

Comment: Great hint! With this I found a DFA that accepts the language! Thank you very much!

Comment: @user3240151: You’re very welcome.